# Combination of points from pre-defined groupings that minimizes distance between the points

Tags: matlab

Suppose you have a matrix with cluster centers and you want to merge them. For example lets say 7 centers:

```
176 187 96
47  52  35
102 112 80
59  60  55
145 156 83
56  54  30
229 255 128
```

I have a function that returns a list of groupings. The rows are the groups and the columns are the indices for the rows of the  original data that are members of that group. For example lets say:

```
     2     4
     1     5
     2     6
     4     6
```

This means that the first group contains points 2 and 4, the second group contains points 1 and 5, etc.

For each grouping, I define the "score" to be the distance between the two points in that group. I also define the cluster center to be the average of the two points within a group.

I would like to determine the grouping that has the smallest distance between points as well as the center of that group in a vectorized way.

Comment: What do you mean by "merged" and how do you defined "best"?

Comment: Merged = mean of the centers. Best combination = centers that have the smallest distance

Comment: What would be the "Best Combination" in your example?

Comment: I have to find the distance form centers 2,4 and 6 and then decide which combination have the smallest distance.

Answer (score 0):

To compute these things, we can first use your `cluster` array to create a 3D array where each grouping is represented by a row, XYZ are represented across the columns, and the third dimension is the grouping of the two centers.

Let's create your original data:

```
orig = [176 187 96; 47  52  35; 102 112 80; 59  60  55; 145 156 83; 56  54  30; 229 255 128];
groups = [2 4; 1 5; 2 6; 4 6];
```

Then we reshape it so that the pairs are lined up along the third dimension

```
data = permute(reshape(orig(groups,:), size(groups,1), size(groups,2), []), [1 3 2]);

%   data(:,:,1) =
%       47    52    35
%      176   187    96
%       47    52    35
%       59    60    55
%   data(:,:,2) =
%       59    60    55
%      145   156    83
%       56    54    30
%       56    54    30
```

Then we can compute the mean for each group

```
centers = mean(data, 3);

%       53           56           45
%    160.5        171.5         89.5
%     51.5           53         32.5
%     57.5           57         42.5
```

And we can find the distances between the two members of each combination

```
distances = sqrt(sum(diff(data, [], 3).^2, 2))

%   24.658
%   45.727
%   10.488
%   25.884
```

The "best" one is the one with the minimum distance

```
[mindist, best] = min(distances);
inds(best,:)

%   2   6
```